# Declare and initialize a map type matrix separately in EIGEN

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to use Eigen:Map with Stride to map two matrices to an array. For example, if

```
arr = {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,17 ,18 ,19 ,20 ,21 ,22 ,23 ,24}
```

I want the mapped matrices to be

```
mat1 = {1, 7, 13, 19;
        3, 9, 15, 21;
        5, 11, 17, 23}
```

and

```
mat2 = {2, 8, 14, 20; 
        4, 10, 16, 22;
        6, 12, 18, 24}
```

The following code works:

```
int nmat = 2;        // number of matrices
int nrow = 3;        // number of rows for each matrix
int ncol = 4;        // number of columns for each matrix
int arr_size = nmat*nrow*ncol; // size of the array.

int *arr = new int[arr_size];

Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat1(arr ,nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic,Dynamic>(nrow*nmat, nmat));
Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat2(arr+1 ,nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic,Dynamic>(nrow*nmat, nmat));

for (int i=0; i<arr_size; i++) {
  arr[i] = i+1;
}

cout <<"mat1 = \n"<<mat1<<endl;
cout <<"mat2 = \n"<<mat2<<endl;
```

The results are:

```
mat1 = 
1  7 13 19
3  9 15 21
5 11 17 23
mat2 = 
2  8 14 20
4 10 16 22
6 12 18 24
```

However, I would like to declare and map the matrices separately like the following code:

```
MatrixXi mat1;
MatrixXi mat2;
new(&mat1) Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > (arr ,nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic,Dynamic>(nrow*nmat, nmat));
new(&mat2) Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > (arr+1 ,nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic,Dynamic>(nrow*nmat, nmat));
```

This will give me Segmentation fault.

If I comment out mat2 like the code below:

```
MatrixXi mat1;
//  MatrixXi mat2;
new(&mat1) Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > (arr ,nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic,Dynamic>(nrow*nmat, nmat));
//  new(&mat2) Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > (arr+1 ,nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic,Dynamic>(nrow*nmat, nmat));
```

Then there is no Segmentation fault, but the Stride is not working. The results are:

```
mat1 = 
1  4  7 10
2  5  8 11
3  6  9 12
```

The reason I want to separate the declaration and initialization is that I want to write a class which mat1 and mat2 are members of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `mat1` and `mat2` are of the type `Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> >`, but when you do it separately, you defined them as `MatrixXi`.

If you want them as a class member, you could follow the general way for an class member object.

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass(int* arr, int nrow, int ncol, int nmat) :
      a(3), v(10),
      mat1(arr, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat)),
      mat2(arr + 1, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat)) {
  }

  int a;
  std::vector<int> v;
  Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat1;
  Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat2;
};
```

the `new` operator is not needed.

Comment: OK for the declaration, but you need to initialize mat1, mat2 using initializer list with either the proper argument, and if not possible (because the parameters are not known yet) initalize them with dummy parameters (0), and use inplace new to re-initialize them.

Comment: @ggael I missed that. initialize list will be better.

Comment: @kangshiyin Thank you, this is very helpful !

Comment: @ggael It seems that using initializer list is a must for this case. Thanks!